# Retrieve Url of category on Magento when creating a custom menu

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, magento-1.7

I am trying to create a custom drop-down-menu with only few specific categories and their respective subcategories. So far I managed to retrieve the Names of the subcategories but links won't work.

I also need to make the main category retrieve its own name and URL automaticly in case it is changed on the back-end of Magento. In this case the category id is 265.

The website I am working on is www.personalproducts4u.co.uk

```
<li class="eight"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>index.php/contacts">Hotel Products</a>
 <?php $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(265); ?>
 <ul>
 <?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
 <li>
 <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl ?>">
 <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
 </a>
 </li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: have you tried this? `echo $category->getUrl();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `$children` collection is of type `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection` and its elements respectively are of type `Varien_Data_Tree_Node`. Calling `getUrl()` on them will return null, they are not `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` objects. However, you can retrieve their request path (url) by calling:

```
$category->getRequestPath();
```

Alternatively you can load the category object by calling:

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getEntityId());
```

And then use the `$cat->getUrl()` call. This loading will add an extra overhead though.

Comment: Would you also tell me how I can automatically get URL and Name for the category on the first line just by using the ID (265)?

Comment: By loading the the first category's object with $main = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(265) you'll get access to its properties, i.e., $main->getName() or $main->getUrl()

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled across another issue and I was hoping you can help. I have created a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588444/how-to-get-subcategories-under-a-custom-menu-on-magento